# Installing cURL from Macports fails

Tags: curl, macports, configure, apt, libusb

I'm trying to install `libusb-devel` using Macports on a friend's Mac (we need it in order to install Osceleton). On my computer, the installation went perfectly well, but I'm stuck while installing it on his.

One of the dependencies of `libusb-devel` is `curl`. However, installing `curl` seems to fail. During the configuration of `curl`, an error message is shown and the installation quits. I'm referred to the log, where this is the relevant part for the error:

```
:info:configure configure: found both libz and libz.h header
:info:configure checking for "/dev/urandom"... configure: error: cannot check for file existence when cross compiling
:info:configure shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_net_curl/work/curl-7.21.4-ppc" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-ipv6 --without-gnutls --without-gssapi --without-librtmp --without-libssh2 --without-nss --without-polarssl --without-spnego --with-ssl --disable-ares --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --with-libidn --with-zlib=/opt/local --disable-dependency-tracking --with-ca-bundle=/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt --host=powerpc-apple-darwin10.7.0 " returned error 1
:error:configure Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: the following items did not execute (for curl): org.macports.destroot org.macports.configure org.macports.build
:notice:configure Log for curl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_net_curl/main.log
```

If I run the configure-script myself, using the command given in the log, all goes well and `curl` is perfectly installed. However, Macports is not happy with this, because I get errors telling me that certain files already exist etc. Also, installing `curl` directly using Macports seems to give trouble.

Because of this, I can't continue the installation of `libusb-devel`, and we need it quite soon for a school project. Can anyone help?

TIA

Comment: This question doesn't belong here. Try apple.stackexchange.com or superuser.com perhaps.

Comment: Please include the log file... what OS X version are you using, also? (Certainly curl installed just fine from MacPorts on my Mac, so I don't think the port is broken.)

Comment: The [logfile](http://pastebin.com/2XAMHv5M). On Max OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like MacPorts thinks it's cross-compiling for PowerPC.  Make sure you've got the right version of MacPorts installed.  If you're not using MacPorts for anything else, just blow away `/opt/local` and install from [here](http://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-1.9.2-10.6-SnowLeopard.dmg).

Comment: You were right. Re-installing Macports did the trick.Thank you very much